How can i make particle or molecular simulation which fills the ground?
I want to create an animation for my portfolio. There is a shot in which the model bursts out from the particles-filled ground, and these particles make waves like in the sand effect in the Dune movie when the sandworm comes. I tried filling the ground with particles, but it wants more than 120k particles for that, so is there any way I can achieve this result?
I am new to particle physics.
This is the inspiration for the waves effect but I want more control on the ground with lit waves.
